# "...la petite fille modèle telle qu'on a toujours essayé d'en définir les cases dans l'éducation des jeunes filles."

Tags: prépositions

> La femme française qui est censée être représentée dans ce concours est tout simplement la petite fille modèle telle qu'on a toujours essayé d'en définir les cases dans l'éducation des jeunes filles.

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre le sens de cette phrase et en particulier la fonction de "en".
Est-ce que cette phrase n'aurait pas du être formulée comme ça :

> "telle qu'on a toujours essayé d'en définir dans les cases dans l'éducation..."

Answer (score 1):

Dans cette phrase, "en" est employé comme complément du nom, en faisant référence à "la petite fille modèle".

> *On a essayé d'**en** définir les cases*. **-->** On a essayé de définir les cases de qui ? De la petite fille modèle.

Les deux phrases pourraient être reformulées de la façon suivante :

> *Nous avons toujours essayé de définir les cases de la petite fille modèle dans l'éducation des jeunes filles. Elle est censée représenter la femme française dans ce concours.*

Le sens est le suivant : dans ce concours, on tente de représenter la femme française avec des caractéristiques identiques à la petite fille modèle "classique", celle de laquelle on s'inspire pour éduquer nos propres enfants.

Comment: Petite objection sur la fonction grammaticale de "en" : c'est un complément du nom (en l'occurence de "cases") et non un COI. Le verbe "définir " est transitif direct et ne peut pas avoir de COI.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr d'être d'accord : dans cette situation, le verbe "définir" est utilisé comme transitif double : "définir les cases de la petite fille" -> double objet "les cases" et "la petite fille". L'objet indirect, "la petite fille", est remplacé dans la phrase d'origine par le "en" avant le verbe "définir. Peut-être que c'est moi qui interprète mal ceci dit.

Comment: Preuve que c'est un CdN et nom un COI: si on met la phrase "on définit les cases de la petite fille" à la voix passive, on a "les cases de la petite fille sont définies". Le COD est devenu le sujet, et "de la peitite fille" reste en quelque sorte attaché à "cases".Si c'était un COI, on aurait "les cases sont définies de la petite fille", ce qui n'est pas une syntaxe correcte.

Comment: En effet, ça me convainc à présent. Merci d'avoir pris le temps de clarifier, j'ai édité ma réponse !

Comment: ... mais je suppose qu'on sera tous les deux d'accord sur un point, sans long débat: qu'elle est alambiquée, cette phrase !

Comment: Ça la rend d'autant plus intéressante à décortiquer !